# Access content://sms/sent in android 2.2(froyo)

Tags: android, sms

i tried to take a data from outbox sms. 
Here is my code.

`Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), null, null, null, null);`

```
    String dateColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("date");
    String bodyColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("body");
    String addressColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("address");

    output += new StringBuilder("\nMessage to: ").append(addressColumn)
            .append("\n\n").append(bodyColumn);
    Toast.makeText(context, output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But when i start the program will be error, and ask to "force close".

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe you need to add the READ_SMS permission? Or can you post your log?

Comment: i already give <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

Comment: First check for what exception it is that is causing the Force Close check in the logcat.

Answer (score 1):

You need add this command before get the cursor values:

```
cursor.moveToNext();
```